# Get CSS property via Appium

Tags: selenium, appium, appium-ios

I want to click on a button only if it is enabled "Green color". To find the color of a button I tried the below ways, but none worked and giving "UnsupportedCommandException"

`MobileElement mobileElement = appiumDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name='Get Quote']"));`

```
String color = mobileElement.getCssProperty("style");
String color = mobileElement.getCssProperty("background-color");
String color = mobileElement.getCssProperty("color");
```

**Exception:**

```
org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: Unhandled endpoint: {
    wildcards =     (
        "session/element/EF010000-0000-0000-8007-000000000000/css/background-color"
    );
} (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds

Driver info: io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver



at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:239)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:41)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.execute(IOSDriver.java:1)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:285)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileElement.execute(DefaultGenericMobileElement.java:45)
at io.appium.java_client.MobileElement.execute(MobileElement.java:1)
at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSElement.execute(IOSElement.java:1)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.getCssValue(RemoteWebElement.java:171)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileElement.getCssValue(DefaultGenericMobileElement.java:177)
at io.appium.java_client.MobileElement.getCssValue(MobileElement.java:1)
at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSElement.getCssValue(IOSElement.java:1)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.ElementInterceptor.getObject(ElementInterceptor.java:40)
at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.interceptors.InterceptorOfASingleElement.intercept(InterceptorOfASingleElement.java:60)
at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSElement$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$d311658.getCssValue(<generated>)
at com.haulhub.pageactions.mobileapp.HomePageAction.clickPendingFilterButton(DemoPageAction.java:73)
at com.haulhub.tests.DotSlipDisplayFiltersTest.verifyPendingTicketMatchesPendingInspectorReview(DemoFiltersTest.java:44)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:109)
```

Comment: getting the same exception for all 3 trials? What is `mobileElement` in `String color = mobileElement.getCssProperty("background-color");` ?

Comment: Do you run this code for web? Because for native ios app getCssProperty will not work, it's not supported.

Comment: How is `mobileElement` defined?

Comment: Please find here `mobileElement = appiumDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name='Get Quote']"));`

Comment: @cruisepandey Yes

Comment: @MaxDaroshchanka any workaround? Maybe using JavaScript or other workarounds? Yes it is native iOS app

Comment: Native ios app doesn't support js/css related methods, it's bouilt with swift or objective c, this is too different tech stack.. I may suggest to take screenshot, then get the element location and try to get the pixel color witing the element area on the screenshot by coordinates.

Comment: Also you might ask the app developers to add another accessibility-id for enabled and disabled buttons. So it would be possible to detect the state with appium (just by element pricence with specific id).

Comment: @MaxDaroshchanka "I may suggest to take screenshot, then get the element location and try to get the pixel color witing the element area on the screenshot by coordinates." Can you post this code in answer?

Comment: Sorry, I'll have no chance to add the code example within a few days. I have only mobile phone for now, no dev env.. But I'll help you after, if no other answers will be posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Appium documentation:

> Get Element CSS Value command only applies to webview contexts

https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/attributes/css-property/

**So it will not work for native context.**

##### Check if element is enabled

There is another way to check if the button is enabled or not:

https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/attributes/enabled

```
MobileElement mobileElement = appiumDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name='Get Quote']"));

if(mobileElement.isEnabled()) {
    mobileElement.click();
}
```

##### Check element color

If you also need to verify the element color, you should take the page (or element) screenshot, then get the element location and try to get the pixel color witing the element area on the screenshot by coordinates.

```
MobileElement mobileElement = appiumDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name='Get Quote']"));

File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot)appiumDriver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(screenshot);
Point elementLocation = mobileElement.getLocation();
// Lets take color at point x=10, y=10 inside the element (0, 0 is the top left)
int checkColorX = elementLocation.getX() + 10;
int checkColorY = elementLocation.getY() + 10;

// Optionaly you may try to take not the page screenshot, but just the element screenshot
// File screenshot = mobileElement.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
// BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(screenshot);
// int checkColorX = 10;
// int checkColorY = 10;


// Getting pixel color by position x and y 
int color =  image.getRGB(checkColorX, checkColorY); 
int red   = (color & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
int green = (color & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
int blue  =  color & 0x000000ff;

System.out.println("Red Color value = "+ red);
System.out.println("Green Color value = "+ green);
System.out.println("Blue Color value = "+ blue);

// Then you need to compare each color with the values, you expect.
```